# Does email clients support CSS Float?

Tags: css, css-float

I just want to know if email clients support float or not?

I can't test Outlook or Thunderbird right now so I'm asking.

Comment: no, email client is not support the float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this [guide](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) for a detailed description of css support in emails